# Single print statement at end of function adds newline - how can this be?

Tags: python

I have my intro to programming final in a few days, and was reviewing some professor code when I stumbled upon this function in a larger project.

```
def show_grid (grid):
    for i in range(len(grid), 0, -1):
        for element in grid[i-1]:
            if element == EMPTY or element == VISITED:
                print (".", end=" ")
            elif element == WALL:
                print("X", end=" ")
            elif element == PATH:
                print("o", end=" ")
            elif element == GOAL:
                print("D", end=" ")

        print()
```

The specific function is just to print a path in a table that has been previously found through backtracking. It uses two things to format that I hadn't seen before, one being the `end=" "` argument and the other being the print statement all the way at the end. I've already found on google that `end=" "` merely replaces the default newline character appended at the end of a string with a space.

When I read this I thought, surely that must just work to print all the strings on a single line, and not as a table like it's supposed to be printed.

If I remove the final print statement this does happen, but when I put it pack it prints like a nice table, like so:

[image: so]

I've tried to look it up but can't find why this works? It's just a single, empty print statement, so I can't find how this would influence the printing of all the above lines?

Comment: You said it in your question: By default `print()` prints a newline at the end.

Comment: Check your indentation. The empty `print()` is inside the outer for loop, so it happens at the end of each row.

Answer (score 1):

`end` is called a keyword argument. And by default it is set to `\n` (a newline character). so calls to print("hello") is the same as print("hello", end="\n") which results in (notice the newline character):

```
>>> print("hello")
hello
>>>
```

Therefore `print()` is equivalent to `print("", end="\n")` which will print a newline character after each columns of elements (notice how it is outside of the for loop) giving your tables rows.

Answer (score 0):

After outputting its arguments, `print` outputs the string specified by its `end` keyword argument. By default, `end` has the value `"\n"`. This value is output no matter how few positional arguments `print` receives. `print()` is equivalent to a more explicit `print("", end="\n")`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two for loops there, the inner for each element in the row, the outer for each row. The print statement is at the end of the outer one, so each row it'll print a new line.